# How to colorize from character ";" to end of line in VIM?

Tags: vim, gvim

For example:

```
G28 X0 Y0 ; home X and Y
```

I'd like the `; home X and Y` portion to be formatted as `MoreMsg` or some other class.

How do I format from `;` to end of line?

Comment: What about searching this pattern to temporarily highlight it? Typing *`<escape>`* then `/;.*$` and *`<enter>`*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is via the built-in `:match` command, as this perfectly fits your needs: You pass it a highlight group, and a pattern to highlight (in the current window; that's the difference to syntax highlighting). So:

```
:match MoreMsg /;.*$/
```

This is fine for ad-hoc, interactive highlighting (lasting longer than the highly dynamic search highlighting), on top of any existing syntax. If you want a permanent highlighting, extending / creating a custom syntax highlighting would be preferred. See `:help usr_44.txt` for an introduction into writing a custom syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this in my syntax file and report back!

Comment: Win! syntax match SpecialChar /;.*$/